# Facebook HASH KEY for Android Signed APK

Tags: android, eclipse, facebook, hash

I am really facing problem with Facebook integration in android application from last couple of days it might be a duplicate question but please help me out .
i have create a android application with Facebook integration every thing is OK and working fine when i have launch application from Eclipse IDE or unsigned apk but when i have used signed APK Facebook not working only showing dialog when i click on that dialog it get disable and nothing happen , i have searched for that and found hash key issue some form tell debug hash key and signed Hash key is different but i am not able to make signed  hashkey please help me .

For Facebook integration i am using Simple Facebook library

I am using Windows OS

Comment: Which OS have you used for development Linux or Windows ?

Answer (score 0):

Please use this code, to generate the HASH key for your Debug or Distributor(signing) Keystore

```
try
    {
        PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getApplication().getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
        for(Signature signature : info.signatures)
        {
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
            md.update(signature.toByteArray());
            String myHashCode = Base64.encodeBytes(md.digest());
            Log.e("-------------FACEBOOK HASH KEY-----------", myHashCode);
        }
    }
    catch(NameNotFoundException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(NoSuchAlgorithmException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(Error e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: what you need to do is, you just have to Run your Signed APK once using the ADB shell in your emulator/device to view your Signed Facebook KEY, put the same hash key generated in you developer.facebook.com app page.

Comment: have you used the `Base64` class provided [here](http://www.filedropper.com/base64)

Comment: i have used same code which you have share now i am trying to follow your comment give me some minute

Comment: you can add multiple HASH KEYS in the facebook app you have created, so add both your debug and your signing hash keys there in the facebook app page.